# MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed

Tags: mapserver

I've been working in a GetFeatureInfo Request but it fails i don't know why...

The error that give me it's something like

> Regular expression error. MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed. msEvalRegex(): Regular expression error. String failed expression test. >

Anybody knows why this is happening?

(The curious thing about this it's that if i run it through PHP fails but if i run it directly over the search bar it works fine!)

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11443/why-cant-i-get-mapserver-to-show-a-raster

The map location is missing or wrongly formatted.

Comment: Not wrong map location for me, but a `?` instead of `&` in the uri query.