# Cannot access MapServer when using Let's Encrypt HTTPS on Apache2

Tags: https, apache2, virtualhost, lets-encrypt, mapserver

I have recently built a website using MapServer for an academic course. The course is finished, but I wanted to continue developing it. The website is using Apache/2.4.53 (Debian), running on Debian 11, set up as a Virtual Host.

I have recently installed https using Let's Encrypt.
The website works when using either http (http://kina3.net/) or https (https://kina3.net/), so I know that https is working.

I can serve up a example file through MapServer when using: http://kina3.net/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=bluemarble&mode=map

However when I try using https://kina3.net/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=bluemarble&mode=map it generates the following error:
`msLoadMap(): Regular expression error. MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed.`

My research ([MS_DEFAULT_MAPFILE_PATTERN validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475877/ms-default-mapfile-pattern-validation-failed)) suggests that problem is because *"The map location is missing or wrongly formatted"*.
However in the apache2 VirtualHosts config file both references point to the same mapfile. See extract from site configuration file below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName kina3.net
    ServerAlias www.kina3.net
#    Redirect permanent / https://kina3.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/kina3.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SetEnv bluemarble "/var/www/map/bluemarble.map"

</VirtualHost>

### ERROR LOGS IN /var/log/apache2/access.log ###

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName kina3.net
    ServerAlias www.kina3.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/kina3.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /****
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /****
    Include /****

    SetEnv bluemarble "/var/www/map/bluemarble.map"

</VirtualHost>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem ... and it's not glorious. Turns out that I had *two* VirtualHosts files running, with the other one taking precedence. So whatever changes I made in the VH example above would have no effect as the other took precedence.
So if you find yourself with a similar problem to me, try running:

```
sudo apachectl -S
```

and see what the `VirtualHost configuration:`  is pointing to.

Also, once you post a link to your own website on StackOverflow, expect regular visits from web scrapers plus various shady IP addresses.